# hs-minor-mode keybindings are undefined or bring up help window

Tags: json

I installed the json-mode package, then added this to my .emacs:

```
(require 'json-mode)
(add-hook 'json-mode-hook 'hs-minor-mode)
```

After opening a json file, I used Describe-variable on hs-minor-mode and found it was set to true.

But when I try to use any of the keybindings listed on [Hide Show](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow#toc2) they don't work.

If I try C-c C-c for example, it says it is undefined.  If I try C-c ESC C-h as shown in the example, the help window opens.  How do I make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I realized my mistake shortly after submitting my question, and rather than deleting it I thought I'd answer in case someone else ends up here.

Many of the keybindings on the [Hide Show](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideShow) page are written in the form

```
C-<something> @ C-<something>
```

I took the @ to simply be a delimiter between the two chained commands, but it turns out it's literally an @ sign (silly me...).  So to execute the toggle hide/show command ( `C-c @ C-c` ), for example, you need to type `C-c` followed by `@` (holding the shift key of course) followed by `C-c`.  D'oh...

Comment: Glad you found the problem.  If you plan to use `hs` a lot, you can always rebind those commands to more convenient keys.

Comment: Time will tell how much time I'm spending in the Json,  but yea the @ key is a bit out of the way haha